# Scrolling page with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

I'm trying to make my whole page scroll when an element is :hovered

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.wrap-who-mobile').mouseover(function(){

      $('html','body').animate({
      scrollTop: .offset(300).top
      }, 300);

    });

});
```

I'm at this point but nothing happens, I'm a total mess with jQuery, can you help me? 
My goal is to move up the page of 300px when `.wrap-who-mobile` is :hovered 

thank you

Comment: The console says this: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'using' in 300`

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.wrap-who-mobile').mouseover(function(){

    $('html','body').animate({
      scrollTop: $('html', 'body').offset(300).top
    }, 300);

  });

});`

Comment: I want to move up 300px from the current position

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/e0Lw4meo/2/ try this and check if it works

Comment: It works SOOO good thank you!!!

Comment: can you help me to make it works also on mobile click?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/e0Lw4meo/4/ this will work on click

Comment: doesn't work on mobile :(

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/e0Lw4meo/7/ try this

Comment: `$('.wrap-who-mobile').on('mouseenter touchstart', function() {`

Answer (score 1):

Use this plugin: https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo

Its easy to include and easy to use:

```
`$('.wrap-who-mobile').mouseenter(function(){
   //basic usage of scroll-top plugin
    $("body").scrollTo(300,'slow',{axis:'y'});
});`
```

Comment: Come on, don't recommend a plugin for something so simple.

Comment: you are right :( but still its a way and if you are using like many scroll effects in your page you can use this plugin to make things easier for u maybe.

Comment: True indeed, if you wanna do a whole lot of this stuff a plugin could be very handy.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Think this should do it:

```
$('.wrap-who-mobile').mouseover(function(){
  var newPos = 300;
  var scrollHeight = $('body').scrollTop();

  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: scrollHeight - newPos
  }, 300);

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e0Lw4meo/3/

Comment: This bring me at pixel Y=300 :(

Comment: Isn't that the idea? Can you explain better want you want then?

Comment: Sorry  if I was confusing.  I want to move up 300px from the current position

Comment: ah, sorry, I understand now.